# I clicked "Continue the partial update" ; Now I have lots of packages to install and I don't want to

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

Due to a supposed problem in my Ubuntu 18's packages, I could not upgrade to Ubuntu 20. Instead of checking what was going wrong with all the packages problems, I solved one or two packages problems (I think) and then, even if some problems were still present (I think), I wanted to start the upgrade to Ubuntu 20 (big mistake...!).

The graphical upgrader (or CLI, I don't remember) told me that I was going to do a Partial Upgrade. I clicked on "Continue". Then, I stopped it.

**I'm still on Ubuntu 18. So the partial upgrade isn't done I think.**

**Now when I type: `sudo apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade`, I get:**

> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

> (lots of packages)

> The following packages will be REMOVED:

> (lots of packages)

> The following NEW packages will be installed:

> (lots of packages)

> The following packages will be upgraded:

> (lots of packages)

> 2009 upgraded, 377 newly installed, 104 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I think all these packages are related to my Partial Upgrade. **However I want to cancel my Partial Upgrade. In other words, I don't want to see all these packages. What should I do?**

## What I've already tried

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` but it didn't work...

Comment: If you log into 18.04 and want to stay that way then try just `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove` and just keep using 18.04

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` outputs: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2013 not upgraded.` and didn't change anything.

Comment: If you just want to use 18.04 then you don't need to worry about them but if you want them gone from the message just upgrade them `sudo apt-get upgrade` as this is only upgrading within 18.04 it's not a distro uograde anymore.

Comment: I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20 but due to some packages bug, the upgrade didn't work. The upgrader asks me for a Partial Upgrade, which I wanted to do but I didn't entirely (I've stopped it at the download step maybe). Now all these packages must be upgraded. I don't want

Comment: I would just do the `sudo apt-get upgrade` on your 18.04 then backup your home folder and anything else you need and then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and hopefully no CLI errors will happen.

Comment: @darth_epoxy not a good solution sry^^ but thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` was rewritten by the upgrader (Ubuntu 18.04.5 word `bionic` was replaced by `focal`, for Ubuntu 20). I have edited this file in order to replace `focal` by `bionic`. Then I've typed `sudo apt-get update`. Now the problem is solved. When I type `sudo apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade ; apt-get dist-upgrade` it works well: I have no package listed!

NB: I looked in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, all the files contain `bionic` so I didn't have to replace anything here.

Comment: Nice work! This will certainly help someone searching for answers to a similar problem. There is always the graphical way of doing this through **Software & Updates / other software**, but I don't think anyone would have spotted the error without your Answer of looking in the **sources.list** file directly.